# Dojo on (events) firing on declaration

Tags: events, dojo

While using the new Dojo Event (on) i'm getting a lot of loops.

I'm calling for the first time as doShowSomeDialog(null).

Why does this function get into a loop?
(dialog has been declared before as dijit/Dialog)

```
doShowSomeDialog = function ( value ) {

var selectName = 'selector';

if ( value ) {

    dialog.set("href", "/url/"+ selectName +"/"+ value );

} else {

    dialog.set("href", "/url");        
    dialog.show();
}

dialog.set("onDownloadEnd", function() {

    on( dijit.byId(selectName ), "change", doShowSomeDialog( dijit.byId( selectName ).get('value')  ) );


}); }
```

It seems that "on" executes on the declaration of the event.

Answer (score 0):

This will execute the method when calling on.  You should wrap it in it's own function.

```
doShowSomeDialog( dijit.byId( selectName ).get('value')
```

should become

```
function() { doShowSomeDialog( dijit.byId( selectName ).get('value'); }
```

Comment: Friendly reminder to accept the answer if it worked for you.  Thanks.